Clarifying a step in a proof for a*0 = 0, for all real a, and checking if an alternative approach is correct
I'm new to proofs and I'm currently reading Apostol Calculus Vol 1. I was asked to prove that $a\cdot0 = 0$, for all real numbers $a$. Here is what I did, and please note at this point, I'm only "allowed" to use the field axioms of the reals, the cancellation theorem, i.e. if $a+b = a+c$, then $b=c$, and the following result, which I'll denote #1, as I'll reference it later:
$\forall a,b,c \in \mathbb{R},$ $$a\cdot(b-c) = ab - ac$$
It is also okay to assume that $ a - b = a + (-b)$, and that $a + -a = 0$.
I've come up with two possible proofs.
I)
\begin{align}
a\cdot 0 + a\cdot 0 &= a\cdot(0 + 0). \\ &= a\cdot 0.
\end{align}
By the existence of an identity element axiom, we can see that $a\cdot 0$ is an identity element. Moreover, we know that $0$ is the identity element for addition (as stated in one of the axioms), and since it follows from the cancellation theorem that the identity element for addition must be unique, then $a\cdot 0$ must be equal to $0$.
II)
\begin{align}
a\cdot 0 &= a \cdot (a + -a)\\
&= a\cdot a + a \cdot -a. \\
&= a\cdot a + a \cdot -a + a\cdot a + -(a \cdot a).\\
&= a\cdot a + a\cdot(-a + a) + -(a\cdot a) \\
&= a\cdot a + a\cdot 0 + -(a\cdot a) \\
&= a\cdot(a + 0) + -(a\cdot a) \\
&= a\cdot a + -(a\cdot a) \\
&= 0.
\end{align}
In the above proof, I tried to only make use of the axioms, and theorems I mentioned above. Since, at this point, I still have not shown that $a\cdot 0 = 0$ (well, that is what I'm trying to prove) and $a\cdot -a = -(a \cdot a)$, I felt that I had to include this all these additional steps to avoid assuming these two results.
Now onto my main question; I have seen a similar approach to II that was much shorter. It went like this:
\begin{align}
a\cdot 0 &= a \cdot (a + -a)\\
&= a\cdot a + a \cdot -a. \\
&= a\cdot a - (a \cdot a), \ \ \text{Using #1}.
\end{align}
I don't see how #1 can justify this proof, and I would appreciate some clarification. Now it is possible that the author of the proof was referencing the approach used to the result #1 instead of the theorem itself but I can't see how the result itself can justify the jump to the last line. Also, I would really appreciate it if you would comment on the correctness and structure of the two approaches I listed above. Thank you.

My question has been downvoted. Why is that? Is there anything wrong with my question or something that needs improving perhaps?

I can't speak for the downvoter, but let me point out two things: (a) Your question is a bit unfocused; you ask both for an explanation and a proof check. Generally we don't accept posts that ask more than one thing at a time. (b) Let me quote from the [tag:solution-verification] tag description: '"Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.'

@BenSteffan Thank you for the clarification, I'll keep that in mind in my future posts.

Your proofs in (I) (with the additional facts about the additive identity) and (II) look fine. You are also correct in that unless you have shown that
$$a \cdot (-a) = -(a \cdot a)$$
the "shorter" proof is not really complete.
But, your proof in (II) might still be simplified as follows. We have
$$a \cdot a + 0 = a \cdot a = a \cdot (a + 0) = a \cdot a + a \cdot 0$$
Now, by "cancelation", we obtain that $0 = a \cdot 0$, as desired.

Thank you for the feedback, and the much shorter additional approach, really appreciate it :)

@paradox11011 Glad that it was helpful!
